# OpenShift HTTPS for python 2.7 and django 1.7

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, openshift

I'm trying to enforce HTTPS redirection for my Django-based web application on OpenShift but following [How to redirect traffic to HTTPS](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202398810-How-to-redirect-traffic-to-HTTPS-) doesn't seem to have any effect. I have put the `.htaccess` file in repo root and in `wsgi` folder but it's just ignored and I still can browse over HTTP.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You may be restart your application from openshift web panel or using rhc client: `$ rhc app restart -a $your_app`

Comment: I did that dozens of times.

Comment: In addition to that, **.htaccess** file should be readable by the web server user. `$ chmod 644 .htaccess` may be necessary. @norbertpy